# How do I change my API lat and long dynamically whenever I click on a new point on my leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, api, leaflet

Hello I just started using API's and more specifically Ambee API. I can fetch/GET but only for one latitude and longitude and display it on my leaflet map. I can change it manually but I want it to change dynamically whenever I type a location on leaflet search bar. Here is my code:

```
const airAPi = "https://api.ambeedata.com/latest/by-lat-lng?lat=12&lng=77";


async function air() {



const response = await fetch(airAPi, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "x-api-key":
        "0b6971e42ac3de1fc7283214f67e40a0638921c67ffee69fd130f4bd301f6e24",
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  let aQI = await data.stations[0].aqiInfo.category
  console.log(aQI)
  let coord = await data.stations[0];
  const { lat, lng } = coord
  marker.setLatLng([lat, lng])
}
air();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the map re-rendering. A condition statement is needed so that the map can change when lat and long change. Got this solution from the leaflet.js open-source GitHub repository. For more issues on the leaflet map check the leaflet repo https://github.com/Leaflet/

```
var container = L.DomUtil.get('map');
      if (container != null) {
        container._leaflet_id = null;
      }
```